# Dataframe column to list if other column is positive

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to convert a dataframe column to a list containing only values if another column has positive values.

| Word | Value | Another Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2 | 1 |
| Second | 15 | 2 |
| Third | -5 | 30 |
| Fourth | 10 | 22 |

The resulting list should look like this:

[First, Second, Fourth]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is named df you can first filter it then select the column Word:

```
filtered_df = df[df["Value"] >= 0]
word_list = filtered_df["Word"].values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the dataframe by the "Value > 0" then take word column values :

```
 df[df["value"] > 0]["word"].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mask the DataFrame with the condition you want match. Second take the view of the DataFrame and return this as list.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(5), 
                   'y': np.arange(5)-2.5})
mask = df.y > 0  # create mask
df.x[mask].to_list()
```